# Canceling/Modifying a PayPal subscription using PHP

Tags: php, paypal, subscriptions

I'm trying to set up a website that allows users to sign up at various membership levels, each at their own price, using PayPal Subscriptions.  I have searched Stack Overflow and gotten numerous very helpful answers about setting up the IPN script, which I have done successfully.  (Thanks!)

My question now is, how does a member cancel their account within my site?  If they cancel using PayPal, my IPN will detect it and act accordingly, but there must be a way for my users to cancel their subscription on my page, right?  Or at least provide a more direct link than simply telling them "log into PayPal, go to this page, and cancel it there"?

I've found scattered references to generic ideas like "have your script send a cancel request to PayPal" or some indication that maybe only the Pro (Advanced?) membership with PayPal allows you to do this, but I haven't found a straight answer that says definitively yes or no, and if so, how.

Can I have my members cancel and/or upgrade/downgrade their PayPal subscriptions through my PHP website, and if so, what code samples or other considerations will I need to make that happen?  Most helpfully, is there a tutorial that can walk me through it?  I'm fairly familiar with PHP/MySQL, but APIs and such are still new to me...

Thank you!

Comment: Having the same problem now? Did you solve the problem in meantime?

Comment: @TamásPap There is a Cancel button provided by PayPal, but I couldn't find a good solution for up/downgrading.  Right now, users simply have to cancel and re-purchase at a different level, which is obviously less than ideal.

Comment: @Nerrolken I know this is an old post, but there is a REST API for paypal that allows you to revise a subscription plan (upgrade/downgrade the plan). The problem I'm having is that the documentation says the user has to re-confirm the upgrade or downgrade. So I'm assuming I need to implement paypal smart buttons for the upgrade/downgrade but my javascript skills are lacking. Have you found an up to date means to perform these actions using current paypal smart buttons?